# How to separate a string with commas after vowel or space and append to an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to add a comma after a vowel or space in a string and append it to an array.
I tried this but does not give me what I want.
For e.g if I enter "a mambo jambo" output should be ['a', 'ma', 'mbo', 'ja', 'mbo'] .

This is my code:

```
text = input("Please enter text : ")
vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
final_string = []
not_vowel = ""
a_vowel = ""
for text_in in text:
    if text_in not in vowel:
        not_vowel = text_in
    if text_in in vowel:
        a_vowel = text_in
    final_string.append(f'{not_vowel}{a_vowel}')

print(final_string)
```

And this is the output after input "a mambo jambo":

```
['a', ' a', 'ma', 'ma', 'ma', 'ba', 'bo', ' o', 'jo', 'ja', 'ma', 'ba', 'bo']
```

what I want is

```
['a', 'ma', 'mbo', 'ja', 'mbo']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter Trcka provides an interesting answer, but here is another approach. This isn't necessarily better, but it may be more clear.

```
s = "a mambo jambo"
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

cur = ""
new = []
for c in s:
    if c == " ":
        if cur != "":
            new.append(cur)
        cur = ""
    elif c in vowels:
        cur += c
        new.append(cur)
        cur = ""
    else:
        cur += c

print(new)
```

Here is another method. It is a bit slower.

```
s = "a mambo jambo"
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

new = []
i = 0
for c in s:
    if len(new) == i:
        if c == " ":
            continue
        new.append("")
    new[i] += c if c != " " else ""
    if c in vowels + [" "]:
        i += 1

print(new)
```

---

For posterity I converter both of these, [Peter Trcka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69585711/2081835), and [JonSG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69586496/2081835) to functions, and ran them through `timeit`. The results are:

1. [Peter Trcka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69585711/2081835): 1.96 (faster)
2. my first method: 2.15
3. my second method: 4.24
4. [JonSG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69586496/2081835): 8.9 (slowest, often an issue with regular expressions including backreferences)

Comment: Yes, my answer is structured for clarity not speed :-)

Comment: I'm also not sure you have the timeit defined fairly (if speed is crucial). My timeit (I will extend my answer with it) also shows Trcka's answer as fastest but my answer and your faster answer are much closer.

Comment: @theherk When I was writing it, I just wanted to send fast answer not fastest solution :). Good to know.

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn’t mean to throw shade. I think they are all fine solutions, and the time difference is negligible and probably irrelevant. I just thought it was an interesting exercise. I set each as a single function as defined by the answered taking the parameters of the string and the list, then constructed and timeit object where the only setup was importing that function from `__main__`. I think it was fair.

Comment: @theherk - I really like your analysis and respect. When I am writing code, and if it's not really necessary I preffer readability above speed (in general of course). This was interesting case when readability and code speed goes hand in hand :).

Answer (score 3):

Far away from optimal, but I hope it help:

```py
text = "a mambo jambo"
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

out_text = text
for vowel in vowels:
    out_text = f'{vowel}|'.join(out_text.split(vowel))

out_text = out_text if out_text[-1] != '|' else out_text[:-1]
print(out_text.replace(" ", '').split('|'))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['a', 'ma', 'mbo', 'ja', 'mbo']
```

If it works don't forget accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is perfectly fine, I think I would use `re` regex and a list comprehension as I believe it provides an easier solution to understand.

```py
import re

def to_sylables(text):
    match_pattern = r"([aeiou ])"
    replace_pattern = r"\1\t"  ## replace the match with itself and a tab
    return [
        x for x
        in re.sub(match_pattern, replace_pattern, text).split("\t")
        if x.strip()
    ]

text = "a mambo jambo"
print(f"\"{text}\" ==> {to_sylables(text)}")
```

This will give you:

```
"a mambo jambo" ==> ['a', 'ma', 'mbo', 'ja', 'mbo']
```

@theherk has timed the various answers to this point and I thought it might be interesting to look at how that is done. My primary motivation for this is that they report my answer is slowest by a wide margin and while I was not expecting to "win" a speed race with regex, I am surprised that it would result in such a large slowdown.

The good news (for me) is that while my answer is still the slowest, it is not as slow as was reported. I believe that @theherk may be including the cost of `import re` when timing and that might or might not be fair.

If you want to run a timeit of the various answers, try:

```py
import timeit

setup_jonsg = '''
import re
text = "a mambo jambo"
def to_sylables(text):
    match_pattern = r"([aeiou ])"
    replace_pattern = r"\1\t"
    return [
        x for x
        in re.sub(match_pattern, replace_pattern, text).split("\t")
        if x.strip()
    ]
'''

setup_trcka = '''
text = "a mambo jambo"
def to_sylables(text):
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    out_text = text
    for vowel in vowels:
        out_text = f'{vowel}|'.join(out_text.split(vowel))
    out_text = out_text if out_text[-1] != '|' else out_text[:-1]
    return out_text
'''

setup_theherk = '''
text = "a mambo jambo"
def to_sylables(text):
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    cur = ""
    new = []
    for c in text:
        if c == " ":
            if cur != "":
                new.append(cur)
            cur = ""
        elif c in vowels:
            cur += c
            new.append(cur)
            cur = ""
        else:
            cur += c
    return new
'''

print(f"jonsg: {timeit.timeit('to_sylables(text)', setup=setup_jonsg, number=1_000_000):.2f}")
print(f"trcka: {timeit.timeit('to_sylables(text)', setup=setup_trcka, number=1_000_000):.2f}")
print(f"theherk: {timeit.timeit('to_sylables(text)', setup=setup_theherk, number=1_000_000):.2f}")
```

For me, this reports results like:

```
jonsg: 2.57
trcka: 1.33
theherk: 2.05
```

So I'm still the slowest, but I would argue that one should implement the easiest solution to understand (which might not be mine) prior to optimizing for what might be negligible performance gains.